# How can we split a pipe delimited field in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
# Intitialise data of lists
data1 = [{'eno_id': '079490-2|0799-2', 'ID':'27808'}, 
       {'eno_id': '1707-2', 'ID':'2019', 'ID':'18945'},
       {'eno_id': '5045-1|5045-21', 'ID':'2020', 'ID':'36618'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
```

[image]

How can I split out, or expand, the column with pipe characters, so it looks like this?

```
data2 = [{'eno_id': '079490-2', 'ID':'27808'}, 
       {'eno_id': '0799-2', 'ID':'27808'},
       {'eno_id': '1707-2', 'ID':'18945'},
       {'eno_id': '5045-1',  'ID':'36618'},
       {'eno_id': '5045-21', 'ID':'36618'}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
```

[image]

Comment: How about a ``for`` in a ``for``? The outer loop would be ``in range(len(df2))``, in this loop, do ``df2['eno_id'][i].split('|')`` and the inner loop ``in range(len(df2['eno_id'][i]))``

Comment: Append everything and make a new df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it like this and then use .explode():

```
df1['eno_id'] = df1['eno_id'].str.split('|')
df1 = df1.explode('eno_id')
```

Comment: That works. I tried the str.split('|') and made some progress, but I didn't know about the explode thing, so that's where I got stuck. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @ASH, Glad I could help! Happy coding!